# Sharing an image to facebook and pinterest like instagram in android app

Tags: android, facebook, twitter, instagram

Hello I am working on an app which is related to photos uploading,I have seen the Instagram app and it asks for sharing to social apps ( facebook,twitter,etc) before posting the image and when we select multiple social platform and move to next step it shares image in background to the selected social platforms(facebook,twitter),I know how to share image to facebook and twitter but at one time i can share to only one social app,as it opens with a sharing dialog(not share image in background like Instagram).So can anybody pls help me or suggest me how to do it?